# How to call a function in React when two components are not mounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, architecture, react-router, components

Calling a (redux) function when a single React component is about to unmount can be done by calling the function inside `componentWillUnmount`. But I'm wondering how to call a (redux) function when two React components (that are behind separate URLs) are not mounted. Here is an example:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route component={Foo} ... />
          <Route component={Bar} ... />
          // Many other routes
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

class Foo extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (!navigated_to_bar()) {
            alert("Clear state");
        }
    }
}

class Bar extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (!navigated_to_foo()) {
            alert("Clear state");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to only call `alert` if the user has moved away from both the Foo and Bar components; they can navigate between those components as many times as they want without triggering an `alert` call.

I'm fairly flexible in terms of the solution I am searching for: I expect I need an architectural paradigm shift. I was thinking the solution might be to make Foo/Bar have a common parent component and adjust the Router somehow.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to use the parent->child hierarchy and update from there. This is the typical react convention; Pass in a function that allows you to update the parents state.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.state = {
      routedToFoo: null,
      routedToBar: null
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(_, prevState) {
     if (prevState.routedToFoo !== this.state.routedToFoo &&
            prevState.routedToBar !== this.state.routedToBar) {
          if (this.state.routedToFoo === false && this.state.routedToBar === false) 
              alert("Clear state");
      }
  }

  /* -- snip -- */
     <Route component={<Foo setRouted={routedToFoo => this.setState({ routedToFoo })} ... />
     <Route component={<Bar setRouted={routedToBar => this.setState({ routedToBar })}/>} ... />
  /* -- snip -- */
}
```

Then inside of Bar and Foo:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.props.setRouted(true);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.setRouted(false);
}
```

Here I am handling the side effect in componentDidUpdate. We listen to see if both values are false and that at least one of the values has been updated from the previous state then we call the "Clear state" alert.

However, if this is not flexible enough then you may want to consider using redux.
https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Or `Context`:
https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was slightly hoping that there would be a solution with less state management involved but maybe there is no way around it.

Comment: There will inevitably be at least some state management. Where you handle that is up to you. Typically for simple components, this is the way it should be done however, like i said in my answer, you could also handle the state in redux but that is a bit overkill for the example you gave imo.